# How to flag/respond to non-question disruptive behavior from hi-rep users

Tags: discussion, flags, bounties, high-rep-users

I was browsing stackoverflow for questions offering bounties, when I came across [Stack vs Heap C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468210/stack-vs-heap-c) , which offered a 100 rep bounty, but upon reading its details, I found that it was disingenuous--that is--it was placed there in protest of the current bounty system:
[image: the confusing bounty]

On wikipedia, I think it would be classified as ["Climbing the Reichstag dressed as Spider-Man"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_climbing_the_Reichstag_dressed_as_Spider-Man) or ["Disrupting Wikipedia to illustrate a point"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Do_not_disrupt_Wikipedia_to_illustrate_a_point), and normally, I would chalk it up to a troll trolling, but this is a high-rep user, potentially dealing with SO politics that are over my head.

I wanted to write a helpful post, because it seemed like there was some sense that the current ones were inadequate, but on the other hand, I might interfere with a protest, or beat a dead horse (in case the answers actually did contain enough detail)

Is there some way to flag a bounty? Would it even be effective to flag such a high-rep user? Should I actually try to post another answer? This seems to be a corner case, that the FAQ, and SO flagging controls (at least for me) didn't quite patch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Omnifarious is in a bit of a bad mood, [immensely dislikes how the bounty system works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138982/why-was-the-bounty-system-destroyed) and probably was a bit annoyed that no one seems to agree with him/her. However, this has already been handled, the [bounty has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8468210/revisions) by a moderator.

In general, if you have a good answer, especially one that's better than the current ones, go for it, bounty or no bounty. As for flagging, when there's no obvious option, flag one of the user's posts for moderation attention and be very specific in your message why you're flagging. In this case, since it involves a bounty, you could have flagged the question itself, regardless that it was posted from another user, and explained in your message that you are flagging for the rant in the bounty message and not the question itself.

Comment: I'll definitely remember that tip about flagging, very helpful. I think the nature of the asked question puts it in a greyer area, where the question is basic, and potentially well-answered, so while I could add more detail, quoting standards, longer examples; without anyone specifically asking for more detail, I'm not entirely sure its necessary.

Comment: @Dave C++ is not my cup of tea, so I can't really tell if the question is sufficiently answered or not. If you feel it is, no point in posting yet another answer, if not, go for it. Completely up to you.